# Can't get the color to change in my JavaScript drawing board

Tags: javascript, html, css

````
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Paint, Inc.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sideNav">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

        <script src="canvas.js"></script>
        <button id="clear">X</button>
        <section id="leftBumper"></section>

        <section id="rightNav">
            <button id='colorBlack'></button>
            <button id='colorBlue'></button>
            <button id='colorRed'></button>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#canvas {
    border: 0.0001px solid white;
}

html {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#clear {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 30px;
    background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.32);
    border: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.32);
    border-width: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: red;
}

#clear:hover {
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#clear:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

#leftBumper {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 5px;
    color: black;
}

#rightNav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 30px;
    background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.32);
    border: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.32);
}

#colorBlack {
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px;
    height: 33.333333333333333333333333333%;
    background-color: black;
    float: right;
    border: black;
}

#colorBlack:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#colorBlack:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

#colorBlue {
    position: absolute;
    top: 33.333333333333333333333333333%;;
    width: 32px;
    height: 33.333333333333333333333333333%;;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    border: black;
}

#colorBlue:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#colorBlue:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

#colorRed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 66.6666666666666666666666666666%;;
    width: 32px;
    height: 33.333333333333333333333333333%;;
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
    border: black;
}

#colorRed:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#colorRed:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //variables
    const clearButton = document.querySelector('#clear');
    const colorChangeBlack = document.querySelector('#colorBlack');
    const colorChangeBlue = document.querySelector('#colorBlue');
    const colorChangeRed = document.querySelector('#colorRed');

    let painting = false;

    function startPosition(e) {
        painting = true;
        draw(e)
    }
    function finishedPosition() {
        painting = false;
        ctx.beginPath();
    }

    function draw(e) {
        if(!painting) return;
        ctx.lineWidth = 7;
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY)
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY)
    }
    //Event listeners
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', finishedPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw)

    //Buttons
    clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearCanvas);

    function clearCanvas() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
function resizeCanvas() {
    //Resizing
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
}
resizeCanvas();
````

I am a beginner to JavaScript.
I want the 3 buttons for color changing to work properly but don't know what to do. Help please.
I tried adding event listeners and functions that would change the color but couldn't get it to work.
Any tips on how to change the color or even add a color wheel rather than just 3 colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to use a color picker to set the color of your canvas stroke you can start with the [color picker native to HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color) as shown below.

```
<section id="colorChoice">
    <input id="color" type="color" value="#000000" />
    <label for="color"> Choose a color</label>
</section>
```

Then you can use an "input" event listener if you want to change the color of something as the user uses the color picker or a "change" event to fire once the color is picked and the color picker window is no longer focused. In your case, since you would only draw when you click out of the picker you would want a "change" event.

You could add something along the lines of the following

```js
const color = document.querySelector("#color");

function changeColor(e) {
    const color = e.target.value;
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
}

color.addEventListener("input", changeColor);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#tracking-color-changes

See it in action: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Abepena/pen/MWyaaVO)

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons just have a background display of a certain color, but that is never being read with JS

Instead add an onclick event to each button, which returns the background property of it.

Or better yet use an input and add an onchange and set the color to it's value